# toggle jquery offsetParent() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").offsetParent().css("background-color", "red");
    });
});
```

```html
<button>Set background-color</button>
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:70%;position:absolute;left:10px;top:50px">
    <div style="border:1px solid black;margin:50px;background-color:yellow">
        <p>Click button to set the background color of the first positioned parent element of this paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I am appling background color to offset parent but I want it too make toggle ,when ever I click button background color red is coming but when ever I click again that background color should be change by using toggle method

Comment: a) Please don't use inline styles. b) Since you will be from now on using CSS, use the click to toggle a class on the element, and put the styles in the classes. For example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to put the style you want to add/remove in to it's own CSS class and then call `toggleClass()`. It's also much better practice to keep your styling rules out of the HTML and JS code (ie. in a separate stylesheet) in this manner. Try this:

```
.on {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    $("p").offsetParent().toggleClass('on')
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uk62qey5/)